# How to detect a specific System Tray Popup/Tooltip

Tags: windows, winapi

I need to detect a specific Windows System Tray Tooltip/Popup (USB Device Not Recognized). I don't seem to be having much luck polling with FindWindow. Is there a hook or something that will show me each one that pops up?

Comment: I don't believe there is - because of the slew of annoying things that programs did/do with system tray icons/popups, there are very few ways for programs to interact with the facility.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: We have problems with a USB device which is a combined modem and GPS. Sometimes we have to power-cycle the modem (when it fails) and when it comes back up it isn't recognised by windows and raises the "USB Device Not Recognised" bubble. We have found restarting windows "fixes" it so we thought a quick (and hacky) solution is to detect the bubble and restart when this error condition occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed it doing the following:

```
HWND    HMyTooltip = NULL, HNew = FindWindow( "tooltips_class32", NULL );

// Cycle through all visible tooltip windows looking for the one we want
while (HNew && !HMyTooltip)
{
    if (IsWindowVisible(HNew))
    {
        HMyTooltip = HNew;

        // If you want to find a particular tooltip, check the text (Note: GetWindowText doesn't work)
        SendMessage( HMyTooltip, WM_GETTEXT, ARRAYSIZE(Title), (LPARAM)Title );
        if (_strnicmp( Title, "USB Device Not Recognised", 22 ) != 0)
            HMyTooltip = NULL;
    }

    HNew = GetWindow( HNew, GW_HWNDNEXT );
}
```

Comment: So you're having to poll for it? Nasty.

Comment: The whole thing is nasty. The fact I'm looking for it in the fist place is nasty - trying to work around failing drivers with a hack to make the system restart etc. Nasty, nasty, nasty!

Comment: You'd better hope these drivers only fail on English language versions of Windows. Surely there is a real solution to the problem. Perhaps a WMI event.

Comment: It is only on English versions. The right solution is that the manufacturer sort their driver out. Meanwhile, guess who has to "make it work"? (quickly!)